# Calculate Year wise age in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

Let's say I have an Employees Table and yearly survey filled by each person.
I have to transform transactional data into prediction data year wise.

Available Data:

| E_ID | TestYear | DateOfBirth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010 | 1947-01-01 |
| 1 | 2011 | 1947-01-01 |
| 1 | 2012 | 1947-01-01 |
| 2 | 2010 | 1990-01-01 |
| 3 | 2011 | 1999-01-01 |
| 4 | 2011 | 1991-01-01 |
| 4 | 2012 | 1991-01-01 |
| 5 | 2010 | 1989-01-01 |
| 5 | 2011 | 1989-01-01 |
| 5 | 2012 | 1989-01-01 |
| 5 | 2013 | 1989-01-01 |

DataFrame I need:

| E_ID | Year | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010 | 63 |
| 1 | 2011 | 64 |
| 1 | 2012 | 65 |
| 2 | 2010 | 20 |
| 2 | 2011 | 21 |
| 2 | 2012 | 22 |
| 3 | 2010 | 11 |
| 3 | 2011 | 12 |
| 3 | 2012 | 13 |
| 4 | 2010 | 19 |
| 4 | 2011 | 20 |
| 4 | 2012 | 21 |
| 5 | 2010 | 21 |
| 5 | 2011 | 22 |
| 5 | 2012 | 23 |

In the new df I need all employees, for all 3 years 2010, 2011, 2022 and their relevant ages in the year 2010, 2011, 2022 respectively.

How to achieve this? Since in the transactional data, I have records for some employees for some years and not for other years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for DataFrame by first rows by `E_ID`, then repeat rows by [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) and assign repeated lists by [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html), last subtract years:

```
y = [2010, 2011, 2012]
df['DateOfBirth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateOfBirth'])
    
df1 = df.drop_duplicates('E_ID')
df1 = df1.loc[df1.index.repeat(len(y))].assign(TestYear = np.tile(y, len(df1)))

df1['Age'] = df1['TestYear'].sub(df1['DateOfBirth'].dt.year)
print (df1)
   E_ID  TestYear DateOfBirth  Age
0     1      2010  1947-01-01   63
0     1      2011  1947-01-01   64
0     1      2012  1947-01-01   65
3     2      2010  1990-01-01   20
3     2      2011  1990-01-01   21
3     2      2012  1990-01-01   22
4     3      2010  1999-01-01   11
4     3      2011  1999-01-01   12
4     3      2012  1999-01-01   13
5     4      2010  1991-01-01   19
5     4      2011  1991-01-01   20
5     4      2012  1991-01-01   21
7     5      2010  1989-01-01   21
7     5      2011  1989-01-01   22
7     5      2012  1989-01-01   23
```

If performance is important avoid `groupby`:

```
#[22000 rows x 3 columns] - groups sizes like in sample data
df = pd.concat([df.assign(E_ID = df['E_ID'].astype(str) + '_' + str(i)) for i in range(2000)], ignore_index=True)
print (df)

         E_ID  TestYear DateOfBirth
0         1_0      2010  1947-01-01
1         1_0      2011  1947-01-01
2         1_0      2012  1947-01-01
3         2_0      2010  1990-01-01
4         3_0      2011  1999-01-01
      ...       ...         ...
21995  4_1999      2012  1991-01-01
21996  5_1999      2010  1989-01-01
21997  5_1999      2011  1989-01-01
21998  5_1999      2012  1989-01-01
21999  5_1999      2013  1989-01-01
```

---

```
In [213]: %%timeit
     ...: df1 = df.groupby('E_ID').agg({"TestYear": lambda x: [2010, 2011, 2012], 
     ...:                         'DateOfBirth': lambda x: list(x)[0]}).explode("TestYear")
     ...: 
     ...: df1['DateOfBirth'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DateOfBirth'])
     ...: 
     ...: df1['Age'] = df1['TestYear'] - df1['DateOfBirth'].dt.year
     ...: 
     ...: 
374 ms ± 4.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [214]: %%timeit
     ...: y = [2010, 2011, 2012]
     ...: df['DateOfBirth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateOfBirth'])
     ...: 
     ...: df1 = df.drop_duplicates('E_ID')
     ...: df1 = df1.loc[df1.index.repeat(len(y))].assign(TestYear = np.tile(y, len(df1)))
     ...: 
     ...: df1['Age'] = df1['TestYear'].sub(df1['DateOfBirth'].dt.year)
     ...: 
     ...: 
21.7 ms ± 337 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your employer Id `E_ID` is unique and the date of birth `DateOfBirth` is also unique you can groupby the employer id and get the date of birth.

For the aggregation functions in the `TestYear` you include a list with the years you want to extract the age and and in `DateOfBirth` you can aggregate with a list, since the values of the list are the same (identic date of birth) you get the first entry:

```py
df = df.groupby('E_ID').agg({"TestYear": lambda x: [2010, 2011, 2012], 
                        'DateOfBirth': lambda x: list(x)[0]}).explode("TestYear")

df['DateOfBirth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateOfBirth'])

df['Age'] = df['TestYear'] - df['DateOfBirth'].dt.year
```

output

```
    TestYear    DateOfBirth     Age
E_ID            
1   2010    1947-01-01  63
1   2011    1947-01-01  64
1   2012    1947-01-01  65
2   2010    1990-01-01  20
2   2011    1990-01-01  21
2   2012    1990-01-01  22
3   2010    1999-01-01  11
3   2011    1999-01-01  12
3   2012    1999-01-01  13
4   2010    1991-01-01  19
4   2011    1991-01-01  20
4   2012    1991-01-01  21
5   2010    1989-01-01  21
5   2011    1989-01-01  22
5   2012    1989-01-01  23
```